# How to store multiple react form data in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, state

I have a page where users can submit forms. They can choose to add new forms to the page(form 2, 3, 4, 5 of the same form type).

I handle that through:

```
handleAddPastMainData() {
  const pastMainData = this.state.mainData[0].pastMainData;

  this.setState({
    mainData: {
      ...this.state.mainData,
      pastMainData: pastMainData.push([])
    }
  })
}
```

Then I map through **pastMainData** to display the added form.

What I am having a challenge with is with the handler for saving the data since the form is nested.

My current state is like this:

```
this.state = {
  mainData: [
    {pastMainData: []},
  ]
};
```

And my handler is:

```
handleMainInputChange = (event) => {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;

  this.setState(state => {
    state.mainData[0].pastMainData[name] = value;
    return state
  })
};
```

A sample form input field in my app is:

```
<Field
  label="Main name"
  id="pastMainName"
  name="pastMainName"
  placeholder="Super Awesome FName"
  value={state.MainData[0].pastMainData.pastMainName}
  onChange={handleMainInputChange}
/>
```

I assign a key to each form when I map through **pastMainData**.

So a user can choose to add more than 5 of the above field input and submit.

When the data is submitted, I want the state to look like this:

```
this.state = {
  mainData: [
    {pastMainData: [[field1], [field2], [field3]},
  ]
};
```

When the user returns, this gives me the option to check number of fields/forms the user has already completed and render them with the saved data.

However, this obviously is not working.
Any way to improve my code and make it more efficient will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you run this code?

Comment: where is `value` defined in `handleMainInputChange`?

Comment: also, not sure why you have _both_ a placeholder and a value on an input field. you should set the placeholder to a previous value, or a default value - that way it is editable, and you can get the new value if the user updates that field.

Comment: I forgot to add the value even though it was in my code - had to clean it up(console.log statements!)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the placeholder

Currently when I run the code, on clicking **Add Form**, it renders the form but continues to the next page.
The call to continue to the next page is only on the **handleSubmit** method.

Also, since the forms are multiple, how do I get the key and use that particular key in the **handleMainInputChange**.

Comment: what are your errors when you run this? I can see a few different ways to do what you are doing, but assuming that we use your approach to start... what are the errors? Personally, i would store the different forms in state as an obj, where each property is a form, who's value is a obj with form data. but that's just one way. but it looks like in `pastMainData: pastMainData.push([])` you are pushing an empty array into state? pls provide more details on HOW this code is failing

Comment: ah okay, so to stop it from continuing to the next page you probably need to `e.preventDefault()` ,  but it's hard to tell without seeing more of the code that handles that....give me a second to think about the next part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently when I run the code, on clicking Add Form, it renders the
>   form but continues to the next page. The call to continue to the next
>   page is only on the handleSubmit method.

To stop it from continuing to the next page you probably need to `e.preventDefault()` on that button.

> "since the forms are multiple, how do I get the key and use that
>   particular key in the handleMainInputChange."

Add the key to the Field, or Form. For example:

```
<Field
  key={key}
  label="Main name"
  id="pastMainName"
  name="pastMainName"
  placeholder="Super Awesome FName"
  value={state.MainData[0].pastMainData.pastMainName}
  onChange={handleMainInputChange}
/>
```

And you should be able to access it like you would any data-attr, if not, you can pass it as a a param to the `onChange` function.

also, maybe it would be easier to work with a different data structure for your state obj:

```
this.state = {
  forms: {
    form1: {},
    form2: {},
    form3: {},
  }
};
```

may make setting and accessing easier in the long run.